# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null (Javascript/Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running into a relatively strange error here.

In my controller, I have an array defined.

```
$scope.results = [];
```

On an ng-keyUp event, I fire this method:

```
$scope.search = function() {

    MyService.findStuff($scope.myModel.searchTerms).success(function(response)     {
    $scope.results = response;
});
```

On the first keyup, the search fires, returns my result, and updates the DOM with the results:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in results">{{ thing.name }}</div>
```

Everything work perfectly, but ONLY ON THE FIRST KEYPRESS.

Afterwards, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

This obviously crashes the Angular app and I'm out to lunch.

EDIT: I Should clarify, that error is thrown BEFORE any of the code in `$scope.search` executes. No query to the server is fired, no console logging is executed, nothing.

I've tracked it down to `$scope.results = response;`. With this line removed, the queries repeatedly fire with no issue. I've noticed that if I try to change results manually (ie. on the keypress I just do something like `$scope.results = [{ name: "Spaz" }]`, it works on the initial firing but not on subsequent firings.

I'm going nuts! What's up?!

Comment: It looks like the `response` is null on the second keypress. Can you use `console.log(response)` before setting the results to see what it is? Also, `console.log($scope.myModel.searchTerms)`

Comment: Give us information on response as suggested by @JamesHay

Comment: Maybe if you changed `$scope.results = response;` to `$scope.results = response || [];`. That, or put an `if` statement that checks to make sure `response` is an array.

Comment: Here's the strange thing. I console.log('search called') inside the $scope.search function, and it logs that on the first keypress. Second, that function seems to not even get called. When I comment out the $scope.results = response line, it logs perfectly. How can code that isn't even executed throw an error?! How is $scope.results = response called before the console.log?

Comment: try creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  until you do, you'll continue to be baffled by this bug and find little help here.  Here is a plunker to get you started: http://plnkr.co/edit/jhkfALsXmCARQwNbmVDZ?p=preview